# uncapitalize all text and replace spaces with underscore in an php array

Tags: php, arrays, replace

I've got this array `$all_regions = system_region_list($theme);`

some values are 'Sidebar first' 'Sidebar second', they should become 'sidebar_first' 'sidebar_second'

any ideas?

Comment: Plenty of ideas. Have you tried anything yourself yet? Any ideas where to start?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
foreach ($all_regions as $key => $value){
   $all_regions[$key] = strtolower(str_replace(' ', '_', $value));
}
```

[php.net - str_replace()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php)

**Edit**

Even better would be the following (I think), because it will be faster because of the internal value pointer. (I will benchmark this)

```
foreach ($all_regions as &$value){
   $value = strtolower(str_replace(' ', '_', $value));
}
```

Comment: Your welcome. Just noticed Rawkode's post. He made the exact same answer but a few seconds earlier. Give him some rep :3

Answer (score 2):

```
foreach($all_regions as $key => $val) {
  $all_regions[$key] = strtolower(str_replace(' ', '_', $val));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a foreach loop on the array, then you run every item through the strtolower() function, and also use the strreplace() function to replace space with underscore.